# How to broadcast on Instagram via obs?

Tags: streaming, broadcasting, obs

I've seen a bunch of paid services that provide the ability to stream to Instagram via obs, but how are they arranged? How can I implement this myself?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search gave me dozens of options. You can use [yellowduck](https://yellowduck.tv/) for example. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rD1ibZ0LOOw) a tutorial on how to use it. An alternative is [promovgram.](https://promovgram.com/?utm_source=medium&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=How%20to%20Livestream%20on%20Instagram%20using%20OBS%20with%20Promovgram) There really are a lot of options, so I would recommend just googling yourself.

Comment: You are not answering the question posed. I'm asking how exactly to implement this myself, and not use a third-party service

Comment: oh right, sorry for misreading. From what I've read, you need to use an API from instagram which only seems to be accessible to companies that apply for it.